# Function as determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j}=1,2,...,n$ we have function

$f((a_{i,j})_{i,j}=1,2,...,n)=\sum_{x \in{Sn}}sgn(x)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{x,(i),i}$

Show that is the determinant.

Hint: we can check that fulfills axiom of determinant.

Any advice how can I deal with it?

Things what we have to show are: change 2 collumns change sign of det, mult by a matrix increase det a times, when in matrix is 0 row det=0, add 2 rows doesnt change det

Comment: How do you define the determinant axiomatically? Alternating multilinear with value $1$ on the identity?

Comment: Could u explain what u mean?

Comment: What is the definition of determinant that you have been given (i.e. what you have to show this formula is equivalent to)?

Comment: Things what we have to show is: change 2 collumns change sign of det, mult by a matrix increase det a times, when in matrix is 0 row det=0, add 2 rows doesnt change det

Comment: I think you should add that to your question statement to clarify it.

Comment: @asd123456 One way to define determinant is by multilinear asymmetric map that maps the identity matrix to 1. Another is recursively, by [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). If the first is your definition you have to check 1) multilinearity 2) antisymmetric property and 3) $det(E_n) = 1$. The other properties like "if two rows are equal, then $det = 0$" follow from that.

Comment: @asd123456 It would be interesting to me to tell from where you've taken this definition of determinant.